Compiler or Clang tidy warning on methods that directly access the file system
my C++ code has calls to classes such as std::ifstream to open a file for reading or std::filesystem methods that iterate over directories or check if a file exists - I intend to abstract these away in wrappers as I'm about to support working both on cloud and on a local filesystem.
I want to prevent someone from adding calls to such methods (i.e. have a compiler warning or a clang-tidy rule that will fail) and only allow accessing the file system using my wrappers.
Is it possible?
I read about #pragma GCC poison but this means I have to list all of the possible methods that I want to ban
I'm still in the assessment stage

"methods such as std::ifstream...." But std::ifstream is not a method.

Only the class itself controls what can be done with them(their objects). Basically, we can control only our own class types not the ones provided by standard.

Perhaps add command line -Difstream=no_ifstream to compilation of all modules that must not reference ifstream and it will surely produce an error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I don't think there's anything pre-built that meets the requirements in
the question, but the
clang-query
tool can be used to construct ad-hoc queries that would.
First, let me elaborate on the presumed requirements:

Report uses of certain classes.  I will focus on std::ifstream but
reporting others is straightforward.

Report uses of certain functions.  I will focus on those in the
std::filesystem namespace.

Report only in user code, not system headers.

Suppress reports in certain parts of user code, such as those that
implement the filesystem abstraction layer we want to force the rest
of the code to use.


Here is a shell-script that calls clang-query to do those things:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

query='m

  expr(
    isExpansionInFileMatching("^/home/"),
    unless(
      isExpansionInFileMatching("my-fs-layer")
    ),
    anyOf(
      hasType(
        hasDeclaration(
          namedDecl(
            matchesName("::std::ifstream")
          )
        )
      ),
      callExpr(
        callee(
          functionDecl(
            matchesName("::std::filesystem")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ).bind("expr")

'

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 filename.cc -- <compile options like -I, etc.>"
  exit 2
fi

# Run the query.  Setting 'bind-root' to false means clang-query will
# not also print a redundant "root" binding.
clang-query \
  -c="set bind-root false" \
  -c="$query" \
  "$@"

# EOF

Explanation
    isExpansionInFileMatching("^/home/"),
    unless(
      isExpansionInFileMatching("my-fs-layer")
    ),

Report when the expression's
expansion location
is in a file somewhere under /home, thereby suppressing a deluge of
reports from system headers.
But, suppress if it has the substring my-fs-layer, thus allowing
certain parts of the code to directly use the filesystem.
Note: Clang regexes are POSIX regexes, which do not support lookahead
(positive or negative), so we cannot use something like
(?!my-fs-layer).
      hasType(
        hasDeclaration(
          namedDecl(
            matchesName("::std::ifstream")
          )
        )
      ),

This matches any expression whose type is a named type and the name has
::std::ifstream as a substring.
Note that if a parameter is declared as std::ifstream &is, the
expression is is not considered to have reference type, as the
reference-ness of the declaration type (conceptually) relates to
lvalue-ness of the expression.  Consequently there is no need to skip
reference types here.
      callExpr(
        callee(
          functionDecl(
            matchesName("::std::filesystem")
          )
        )
      )

This matches any call to a function whose name has ::std::filesystem
as a substring.
See AST Matcher Reference
for more details on these and other matchers.
Example run
Given report.cc:
// report.cc
// Report file system access.

#include <filesystem>        // std::filesystem
#include <fstream>           // std::ifstream

namespace NS {

int f1()
{
  std::ifstream is("filename");                  // reported
  int i;
  is >> i;                                       // reported
  return i;
}

int f2(std::ifstream &is)
{
  int i;
  is >> i;                                       // reported
  return i;
}

bool f3()
{
  return std::filesystem::exists("something");   // reported
}

}

// EOF

and my-fs-layer.cc:
// my-fs-layer.cc
// Stand-in for a filesystem abstraction layer that *is* allowed to
// access the FS directly.

#include <filesystem>        // std::filesystem
#include <fstream>           // std::ifstream

namespace myfs {

int f1()
{
  std::ifstream is("filename");
  int i;
  is >> i;
  return i;
}

int f2(std::ifstream &is)
{
  int i;
  is >> i;
  return i;
}

bool f3()
{
  return std::filesystem::exists("something");
}

}

// EOF

the script (which I called cmd.sh) produces the output:
$ ./cmd.sh my-fs-layer.cc report.cc --

Match #1:

$PWD/report.cc:11:17: note: "expr" binds here
  std::ifstream is("filename");                  // reported
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

$PWD/report.cc:13:3: note: "expr" binds here
  is >> i;                                       // reported
  ^~

Match #3:

$PWD/report.cc:20:3: note: "expr" binds here
  is >> i;                                       // reported
  ^~

Match #4:

$PWD/report.cc:26:10: note: "expr" binds here
  return std::filesystem::exists("something");   // reported
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 matches.

